# How to balance damage and Armour/HP?

Tags: diablo-iii

So right now, I have a "Lightning Crusader". All damage and attacks are based around the ability to deal lightning damage, generally in an AoE pattern. Admittedly, it's not overly optimized, but it does well enough.

I'm running around on Torment IX, and I am quite capable of dealing damage to kill almost everything in a decent time frame, my primary crutch is taking damage. Any arcane beams wipe me out instantly, even the Succubi and Herald of Pestilence's attacks can KO me in one or two hits.

[Hero Link](https://us.diablo3.com/en/profile/WoulfMan1024-1753/hero/119184104)

[image]

- Strength: 8,525
- Dexterity: 77
- Intelligence: 77
- Vitality: 4,231
- Damage: 354,748
- Toughness: 12,317,400
- Recovery: 1,375,210

I have been primarily focusing on Armor, Life per Hit, and recovery with my paragon levels (currently at 332 with this character), but at this point I am still getting wrecked.

What levels should I be at in Torment IX?

Comment: A link to the character page would help far more, as we would be able to see the actual stats of each armor piece (which we cant in the picture). Also would be good to know the skills you use

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Edited (I think)

Comment: Every set in the game has associated [builds](https://www.diablofans.com/builds), just stick to one proved to be working and you should be fine. It may still work if you miss an item or two, but you surely have to know which items to look for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays it is really not about levels, it is about gear. Only gear. You can already kill T XVI if your gear/build is good.

For the build you chose, you need a few more defensive items.

Items you miss:

- Belt: [Sacred Harness](https://us.diablo3.com/en/item/sacred-harness-P3_Unique_Belt_01) - enemies deal 40% less damage after casting "Falling Sword"
- Necklace: [The Traveler's Pledge](https://us.diablo3.com/en/item/the-travelers-pledge-Unique_Amulet_008_x1) - used with ring - up to 50% damage reduction while moving
- Ring: [The Compass Rose](https://us.diablo3.com/en/item/the-compass-rose-Unique_Ring_013_x1) - used with necklace - up to 50% damage reduction while moving

Alone with these items your survivability should skyrocket already. Then there are also skills that provide even more survivability.

In a build I found the skills for survivability are:

- [Provoke](https://us.diablo3.com/en/class/crusader/active/provoke) with the "Too Scared to Run" rune
- [Iron Skin](https://us.diablo3.com/en/class/crusader/active/iron-skin)
- [Akarat's Champion](https://us.diablo3.com/en/class/crusader/active/akarats-champion) with the "Prophet" rune
- [Finery](https://us.diablo3.com/en/class/crusader/passive/finery) - strength = armor

Regarding your paragon points, generally the first 50 points in the defensive tree go into "Resist All", then 50 into "Armor" and afterwards 50 into "Life". In the utility tree, it doesn't really matter, but some builds profit more from "Area Damage" or "Resource Cost Reduction" and life on hit is mostly at the 3rd place.

---

I will not go into the playstyle of the build or which stats you should roll on each item piece as that is not the scope of the question. If you are interested in these, check the links below. If you follow this build guide, you will quickly be in T XVI

https://www.icy-veins.com/d3/blessed-hammer-crusader-bis-gear-gems-paragon-points

https://www.icy-veins.com/d3/crusader-hammerdin-build-with-blessed-hammer-and-seeker-of-the-light-set

https://www.icy-veins.com/d3/blessed-hammer-crusader-skills-and-runes

Comment: Well, you're not wrong! I've changed things up a bit and I've jumped straight to Torment X, with minimal issues. Just gotta get used to the small change in playstyle and it's all good! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Overall every build is capable of doing T XVI, they just require a specific playstyle and some very specific items in most cases